# loading jsp page taking too long time

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

In my project, JSP pages loading times taking too long. I have a lot of javascript codes and ajax calls in my jsp pages. One of my jsp pages codes like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="org.solr.dbJava"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@page import="org.solr.SolrJava" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList"%>
<%@page import="org.solr.userSolrJava" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>TEC E-Archive</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css//jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css//bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css//jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image" href="images//TEC.jpg">
<style>
{box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 10%;
  width: 55%;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 10%;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
  width:55%;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}


/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<script src="js//jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="js//bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js//jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="js//jquery-ui.js"></script>
<%      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");Connection connect=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.18.132.29:1521:xe","SYSTEM","orc2002admin#");Statement state=connect.createStatement();%>
<script>
function salesOrder(){
    var salesOrder=$("#sOrder option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'getValues',
        data:'salesOrder='+salesOrder,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            var results=JSON.stringify(data);
            document.getElementById("induction").value=data[0];
            document.getElementById("customer").value=data[1];
            document.getElementById("operator").value=data[2];
            document.getElementById("rem_reason").value=data[3];
            document.getElementById("tsn").value=data[4];
            document.getElementById("csn").value=data[5];
            document.getElementById("tslsv").value=data[6];
            document.getElementById("cslsv").value=data[7];
        }
    });
};
</script>
<script>
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example_table' )){
    var table = $('#example_table').DataTable();
}
$(document).ready(function fill_table(){
    $('#example_table tbody').html('');
    var URL="http://localhost:8983/solr/StorageCore/select?q=*%3A*&rows=9999&sort=idCopy%20desc&start=0&wt=json";
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'json',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            var html='';        
            $.each(docs,function(key,value){
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.ID+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                if(value.strLocation==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strLocation+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strBox+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strFolder+'</td>';
                if(value.strCustomer==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strCustomer+'</td>';
                if(value.strOperator==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strOperator+'</td>'; 
                html+='<td>'+value.strDate+'</td>';
                if(value.strElectronicStoredDate==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strElectronicStoredDate+'</td>';
                if(value.strStoredDate==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strStoredDate+'</td>';
                if(value.strShippedDate==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strShippedDate+'</td>';
                if(value.strSubmitName==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strSubmitName+'</td>';
                if(value.strSubmitDate==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.strSubmitDate+'</td>';
                if(value.ExpiryDate==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.ExpiryDate+'</td>';
                if(value.Destructed==undefined)
                    html+='<td></td>';
                else
                    html+='<td>'+value.Destructed+'</td>';  
                html+='</tr>';
            });
            
            $('#example_table').DataTable().destroy();
            $('#example_table tbody').html(html);
            var table=$('#example_table').DataTable({
                "paging":true,
                "searching":false,
                "scrollY":"500px",
                "scroller":true,
                "pageLength":250,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "colReorder": true,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "400%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
            });
        },
    });
})
</script>
<script>
function openForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    var salesOrder="\""+$("#sOrder option:selected").val()+"\"";
    document.getElementById("sOrder_popup").value=$("#sOrder option:selected").val();
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/StorageCore/select?q=strSO:"
    var URL_MIDDLE="&rows=99999&start=0&wt=json"
    var URL=URL_PREFIX+salesOrder+URL_MIDDLE;
    $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'json',
        type:'get',
        json : 'json.wrf',
        cache :false,
        success : function(data) {
            var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strLocation===undefined)
                document.getElementById("location_popup").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("location_popup").value=jsonData[0].strLocation[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strSubmitName===undefined)
                document.getElementById("submitted_popup").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("submitted_popup").value=jsonData[0].strSubmitName[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strSubmitDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("subDate_popup").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("subDate_popup").value=jsonData[0].strSubmitDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strBox===undefined)
                document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=0;
            else
                setBoxOption(jsonData[0].strBox);
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strEditName===undefined)
                document.getElementById("editedBy").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("editedBy").value=jsonData[0].strEditName[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strFolder===undefined)
                document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=0;
            else
                setFolderOption(jsonData[0].strFolder);
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strEditDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("editDate").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("editDate").value=jsonData[0].strEditDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("releaseDate").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("releaseDate").value=jsonData[0].strDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].ExpiryDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("expiryDate").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("expiryDate").value=jsonData[0].ExpiryDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strStoredDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("hardCopy").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("hardCopy").value=jsonData[0].strStoredDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].Destructed===undefined)
                document.getElementById("destructed").selectedIndex=0;
            else
                setDestOption(jsonData[0].Destructed[0]);
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strElectronicStoredDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("electronic").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("electronic").value=jsonData[0].strElectronicStoredDate[0];
            if(jsonData[0]===undefined||jsonData[0].strShippedDate===undefined)
                document.getElementById("outSource").value="";
            else
                document.getElementById("outSource").value=jsonData[0].strShippedDate[0];

        },
        });
}
function closeForm(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    location.reload();
}
function setBoxOption(optValue){
    if(optValue==0)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=0;
    else if(optValue==1)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=1;
    else if(optValue==2)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=2;
    else if(optValue==3)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=3;
    else if(optValue==4)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=4;
    else if(optValue==5)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=5;
    else if(optValue==6)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=6;
    else if(optValue==7)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=7;
    else if(optValue==8)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=8;
    else if(optValue==9)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=9;
    else if(optValue==10)
        document.getElementById("boxCount").selectedIndex=10;
}
function setFolderOption(optFolderValue){
    if(optFolderValue==0)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=0;
    else if(optFolderValue==1)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=1;
    else if(optFolderValue==2)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=2;
    else if(optFolderValue==3)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=3;
    else if(optFolderValue==4)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=4;
    else if(optFolderValue==5)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=5;
    else if(optFolderValue==6)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=6;
    else if(optFolderValue==7)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=7;
    else if(optFolderValue==8)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=8;
    else if(optFolderValue==9)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=9;
    else if(optFolderValue==10)
        document.getElementById("folderCount").selectedIndex=10;
}
function setDestOption(optValue){
    if(optValue=="YES")
        document.getElementById("destructed").selectedIndex=1;
    else if(optValue=="NO")
        document.getElementById("destructed").selectedIndex=2;
}
</script>
<script>
function addSO(){
    var salesOrder=$("#sOrder_popup").val();
    var location=$("#location_popup").val();
    var box=$("#boxCount option:selected").val();
    var folder=$("#folderCount option:selected").val();
    var customer=$("#customer").val();
    var operator=$("#operator").val();
    var releaseDate=$("#releaseDate").val();
    var electronic=$("#electronic").val();
    var hardCopy=$("#hardCopy").val();
    var shipped=$("#outSource").val();
    var submitName=$("#submitted_popup").val();
    var submitDate=$("#subDate_popup").val();
    var expiryDate=$("#expiryDate").val();
    var destructed=$("#destructed").val();
    var editName=$("#editedBy").val();
    var editDate=$("#editDate").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'addStorage',
        data:'salesOrder='+salesOrder+'&location='+location+'&box='+box+'&folder='+folder+'&customer='+customer+'&operator='+operator+'&releaseDate='+releaseDate+'&electronic='+electronic+'&hardCopy='+hardCopy+'&shipped='+shipped+'&submitName='+submitName+'&submitDate='+submitDate+'&expiryDate='+expiryDate+'&destructed='+destructed+'&editName='+editName+'&editDate='+editDate,
        dataType:'text/plain',
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='Adding SalesOrder is successfull.';
        }
    });
};
</script>
<script>
function editSO(){
    var salesOrder=$("#sOrder_popup").val();
    var location=$("#location_popup").val();
    var box=$("#boxCount option:selected").val();
    var folder=$("#folderCount option:selected").val();
    var customer=$("#customer").val();
    var operator=$("#operator").val();
    var releaseDate=$("#releaseDate").val();
    var electronic=$("#electronic").val();
    var hardCopy=$("#hardCopy").val();
    var shipped=$("#outSource").val();
    var submitName=$("#submitted_popup").val();
    var submitDate=$("#subDate_popup").val();
    var expiryDate=$("#expiryDate").val();
    var destructed=$("#destructed").val();
    var editName=$("#editedBy").val();
    var editDate=$("#editDate").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'updateStorage',
        data:'salesOrder='+salesOrder+'&location='+location+'&box='+box+'&folder='+folder+'&customer='+customer+'&operator='+operator+'&releaseDate='+releaseDate+'&electronic='+electronic+'&hardCopy='+hardCopy+'&shipped='+shipped+'&submitName='+submitName+'&submitDate='+submitDate+'&expiryDate='+expiryDate+'&destructed='+destructed+'&editName='+editName+'&editDate='+editDate,
        dataType:'text',
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='Editing SalesOrder is successfull.';
        }
    });
};
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 25px">
        <div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; text-align: left">
            <img border="0" src="images//TEC.jpg" alt="TEC" width="170"
                height="75">
        <font size="6"> Electronic Archiving</font>
        <%
        String USERNAME=null;
        String fullname=null;
        Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
        if(cookies!=null){
            for(Cookie cookie:cookies){
                if(cookie.getName().equals("USERNAME"))USERNAME=cookie.getValue();
            }
        }
        if(USERNAME==null) response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
        ArrayList<String> strSO=new ArrayList<String>();
        ResultSet rs1=state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERT WHERE USERNAME='"+USERNAME+"'");
        while(rs1.next())
            fullname=rs1.getString("NAME")+" "+rs1.getString("LASTNAME");

        %>
</div>
        <div style="margin-left:75%;">
        <label>Welcome <b><%=fullname %></b>, Login successful.</label></div><div style="margin-left:74%;"><form action="returnToFirstPageServlet" method="post"><button class="btn btn-sm">Return to First Page</button></form></div>
        <div style="margin-left: 85%; margin-top:-30px;"><form action="LogoutServlet" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-sm"></form></div>
        <br>
        <div style="margin-left:7%; margin-right:10%; border-style:groove;">
            <div style="margin-right:65&; margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px;" >
                <label for="salesOrder">Sales Order</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id="sOrder" style="margin-left:58px; margin-top:3px;" onchange="salesOrder()"><% ResultSet rs=state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SalesOrder WHERE strSO LIKE 'E%' OR strSO LIKE 'R%'"); while(rs.next()){ %><option><%=rs.getString("strSO") %></option><%} %></select>&emsp;&emsp;<br>
                <label>Ind. Date:</label>&emsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="induction" style="margin-left:59px;" size="15"><br>
                <label>Customer:</label>&nbsp;<textarea  id="customer" rows="1" cols="10" wrap="soft" style="margin-left:70px;"></textarea>&emsp;<label>Operator:</label>&nbsp;<textarea id="operator" rows="1" cols="10" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
                <label>Removal Reason:</label>&emsp;<textarea rows="2" cols="30" wrap="soft" id="rem_reason" style="margin-left:10px; height:50px; text-size:10px;"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <div style="margin-left:40%; margin-top:-70px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add / Edit / Show Sales-Order" onclick="openForm()" style="height:70px;white-space:normal;width:150px; margin-left:15%;">
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:70%; margin-top:-130px;">
                <label>TSN:</label>&emsp;&ensp;<input type="text" id="tsn" style="margin-left:1px;"><br>
                <label>CSN:</label>&emsp;&ensp;<input type="text" id="csn" style="margin-left:-0.5px;"><br>
                <label>TSLSV:</label>&ensp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="tslsv" style="margin-left:-1px;"><br>
                <label>CSLSV:</label>&ensp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="cslsv" style="margin-left:-3px;">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                <form class="form-container">
                    <h3>Add or Edit Archived Sales-Order</h3><br>
                    <label>Sales-Order:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="sOrder_popup" size="10" style="margin-left:84px;" readonly>&emsp;&emsp;<label>Submitted By:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="submitted_popup" value="<%=fullname %>" size="20" readonly><br>
                    <label>Location:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="location_popup" size="10" style="margin-left:107px;">&emsp;&emsp;<label>Submit Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="subDate_popup" size="20" style="margin-left:6.5px;" value="<%Date date=new Date(); %>" readonly><br>
                    <label>Box Count:</label>&emsp;<select id="boxCount" style="margin-left:94px;"><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option></select>&emsp;&emsp;<label style="margin-left:82px;">Edited By:&emsp;</label><input type="text" id="editedBy" style="margin-left:44.5px;" value="<%=fullname %>" readonly><br>
                    <label>Folder Count:</label>&emsp;<select id="folderCount" style="margin-left:76px;"><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option></select>&emsp;&emsp;<label style="margin-left:81px;">Edit Date:&emsp;</label><input type="text" id="editDate" style="margin-left:46.25px;" value="<%Date editDate=new Date(); %>" readonly><br>
                    <label>Engine Release Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="releaseDate" style="margin-left:23px;" size="10">&emsp;&ensp;<label style="margin-left:7px;">Doc. Expiry Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="expiryDate" size="10"><br>
                    <label>HardCopy Storage Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="hardCopy" style="margin-left:-2px;" size="10">&emsp;&ensp;<label style="margin-left:7px;">Destructed:</label>&emsp;<select id="destructed" style="margin-left:38.5px;"><option>-</option><option>YES</option><option>NO</option></select><br>
                    <label>Electronic Storage Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="electronic" size="10">&emsp;&ensp;<label style="margin-left:7px;">OutSource Shipping Date:</label>&emsp;<input type="text" id="outSource" size="10"><br>
                    <button type="button" onclick="addSO()">Add Sales-Order</button>&emsp;&emsp;<button type="button" onclick="editSO()">Edit Sales-Order</button>&emsp;&emsp;<button type="button" onclick="closeForm()">Exit</button>&emsp;&emsp;<b><label id="result" style="color:red;"></label></b>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div style="margin-left:7%;margin-right:10%;">
            <table id="example_table" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:3%;">ID</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:7%;">Sales-Order</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Location</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:3%;">Box</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:3%;">Folder</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Release Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Electronic Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Hard Storage<br>---------------<br>Internal Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Shipping Date<br>---------------<br>Outsourced Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Submit Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Submit Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:6%;">Expiry Date<br>---------------<br>Internal Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width:3%;">Destructed?</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="font-size:11px;"></tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr style="font-size:11px;">
                        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Sales-Order</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Location</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Box</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Folder</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Customer</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Operator</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Release Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Electronic Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Hard Storage<br>---------------<br>Internal Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Shipping Date<br>---------------<br>Outsourced Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Submit Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Submit Date</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Expiry Date<br>---------------<br>Internal Storage</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Destructed?</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why it takes too long time like this. The jsp page's loading time looks like in this picture

[image: time]

Loading off **storage.jsp**'s document type takes 362,28 s and it's too long. Does anyone have any suggestion for this problem?

[image: the timings]

Comment: Try removing the ajax calls from the document.ready and then see the performance of your jsp page if It proves your ajax class are slowing down the page if still the same then are the subsequent calls the your jsp page take the same time if you refresh your page does it take the same time? The very first call to your jsp page is going to be slow as the server container needs to load the jsp page. Other thing is see is you are doing everything in jsp maybe do the processing in a servlet and then the jsp does the only the display part using JSTL as this might improve readability of your jsp page

Comment: @SukhvirThapar I removed all JS and AJAX calls from my .jsp page but still takes too long time to be load. Also I removed all **document.ready** functions but still the same as before.

Comment: I see you have made a connection to database but I can't see the termination of that connection maybe that could be it but I doubt it.

Comment: @SukhvirThapar The possible cause could be cookies? However, I added the timings. It's downloading something but I'm working on localhost in my computer. It doesn't need to download something, I consider.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check your DB connectivity or other resources where you are making a connection and that is not available unfortunately. It will lead into infinite loading behavior.

Also, implement timeout session and break the connection to prevent more cpu/memory utilization.